# Usar password_verify() con archivos diferentes

Tags: php, html, web, formularios

Tengo un sistema de login/registro. En la pagina de registro, cuando el usuario se crea una cuenta, uso `password_hash()` para hashear la contraseña de esta manera:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$contraseña_hasheada= password_hash($contraseña , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Esto en la pagina de registro. Mi problema es en el login al usar `password_verify()`. El registro y el login estan en 2 archivos diferentes. En el login hago esto con la contraseña:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$email = $_POST['email']

$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
$statement->execute();
$resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (password_verify($contraseña, $resultado)) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $email;
    header('Location: main.php');
}else{
    $errores = '<p>La cuenta no existe</p>';
}
```

Hasta donde yo se, `password_verify()` necesita 2 valores, la contraseña escrita en el formulario, que en este caso seria `$_POST['contraseña']` y la contraseña traida desde la base de datos, que en este caso creo que seria `$resultado`. Al hacer esto el codigo me lleva al `else` del `password_verify()` de aca arriba, lo que marca el error de, "la cuenta no existe".

¿Por qué esta sucediendo esto y como puedo trabajar con el `password_verify()`? Soy nuevo en esto de las contraseñas.

Edit: Ya he visto otras preguntas similares pero no responden a lo que estoy buscando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás pidiendo el *resultado* como un array asociativo (**PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**). Para acceder al valor tenés que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$resultado['contraseña']
```

Debería quedar algo así:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute([':email' => $email]);
$resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if( password_verify($contraseña, $resultado['contraseña']) ) {
    echo 'La clave es correcta';
} else {
    echo 'La clave es incorrecta';
}
```

Si solo vas a obtener la contraseña no es necesario pedirlo que te lo devuelva en un array asociativo. Lo podés hacer directo con **PDO::FETCH_COLUMN**

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute([':email' => $email]);
$contraseña_hasheada = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

if( password_verify($contraseña, $contraseña_hasheada) ) {
    echo 'La clave es correcta';
} else {
    echo 'La clave es incorrecta';
}
```